# How can I write a method or a for loop for very similar code pieces

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, machine-learning, methods

I have a code sample below. Code works perfectly but my problem is, this code isn't clean and costing too much line, I believe this code can be reduced with a method or for-loop, but I couldn't figure out how can I achieve this. The code pieces are %90 same, only changes are happening in variable side. I only put 2 of the pieces but my code consists of 5 pieces just like this

```
#KFOLD-1

all_fold_X_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sentence_txt'])
index = 0
for k, i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_txt'].values):
    if k in kFoldsTrain1:
        all_fold_X_1 = all_fold_X_1.append({index:i}, ignore_index=True)

X_train1 = count_vect.fit_transform(all_fold_X_1[0].values)

Y_train1 = [i for k,i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_Polarity'].values) if k in kFoldsTrain1]
Y_train1 = np.asarray(Y_train1)

#KFOLD-2

all_fold_X_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sentence_txt'])
index = 0
for k, i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_txt'].values):
    if k in kFoldsTrain2:
        all_fold_X_2 = all_fold_X_2.append({index:i}, ignore_index=True)

X_train2 = count_vect.fit_transform(all_fold_X_2[0].values)

Y_train2 = [i for k,i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_Polarity'].values) if k in kFoldsTrain2]
Y_train2 = np.asarray(Y_train2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full example hasn't been provided, so I'm making some assumptions. Perhaps something along these lines:

```
def train(dataVar, dfNew):
    ret = {}
    index = 0
    for k, i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_txt'].values):
        if k in kFoldsTrain1:
            dataVar = dataVar.append({index:i}, ignore_index=True)

    ret['x'] = count_vect.fit_transform(dataVar[0].values)
    ret['y'] = [i for k,i in enumerate(dfNew['Sentence_Polarity'].values) if k in kFoldsTrain1]
    ret['y'] = np.asarray(Y_train1)

    return ret

#KFOLD-1
kfold1 = train(pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sentence_txt']), dfNew)

#KFOLD-2
kfold2 = train(pd.DataFrame(columns=['Sentence_txt']), dfNew)
```

You perhaps get the idea. You may not need the second argument in the function dependent on if the variable 'dfNew' is global. I'm also far from a Python expert! ;)